# What better way to write a HashMap inserting?

Tags: java

Here i have simple class Doctor

```
public class Doctor {
    private int id;
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String speciality;
    
    //constructor
    //getters
    //setters
```

Here is a list of doctors

```
List<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<>();
        doctorList.add(new Doctor(1, "Smith", "John", "laryngologist"));
        doctorList.add(new Doctor(2, "Duncan", "Sylvester", "dentist "));
        doctorList.add(new Doctor(3, "Reid", "Otis", "dentist "));
        doctorList.add(new Doctor(4, "Jenkins", "Ford", "oculist "));
        
        
Map<String, Integer> specializationAmountOfDoctors = new HashMap<>(); // key: specialization , value: amount of doctors
```

**I want to count which specialization is the most using HashMap.**

**How can I write better way this code ? :**

(Maybe using Stream ?)

```
for (Doctor d : doctorList) {
            if(!specializationAmountOfDoctors.containsKey(d.getSpeciality())){
                specializationAmountOfDoctors.put(d.getSpeciality(), 1);
            } else {
                int tmp = specializationAmountOfDoctors.get(d.getSpeciality());
                specializationAmountOfDoctors.put(d.getSpeciality(), tmp+1);
            }
        }
```

To get Max from Map i have using Stream :

`Map.Entry<String, Integer> specializationMax = specializationAmountOfDoctors.entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).get();`

*Thanks*

Comment: As @Eritrean suggested, using the stream api will help you with that, for that you need to access the map entry set and the using the stream methods you can invoke the Collectors. groupingBy or other related methods. Check if you are using java 11 o 16 because they added some new ones

Comment: Better is over here based on performance and optimisation? This is subject to Compute Complexity and Space Complexity. If you are looking at readability & cleaner code, sure lambda functions do that

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I would utilise an enumeration to represent the possible values of *speciality*:-

```
public enum Speciality {
    LARYNGOLOGIST, DENTIST, OCULIST
}
```

You can use the Streams API to perform a count of the number of objects that match a certain criteria:-

```
final Speciality expected = Speciality.DENTIST; 
final long count = doctorList.stream()
                       .filter(d -> d.getSpeciality().equals(expected)).count();
```

Following the approach you have made above, you could populate the map like so:-

```
final Map<Speciality, Long> specialityMap = new HashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(Speciality.values()).forEach(s -> {
    final long count = doctorList.stream()
                           .filter(d -> d.getSpeciality().equals(expected)).count();
    specialityMap.put(s, count);
});
```

But a better approach would be to use the `Collectors.groupingBy` functionality:-

```
final Map<String, List<Doctor>> grouped = doctorList.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Doctor::getSpeciality));
```

Though this returns a slightly different output to what you were expecting so you will need to handle that accordingly. @Eritrean came up with a great suggestion to use a second Collector like so:-

```
Map<String, Long> grouped = doctorList.stream()                        
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Doctor::getSpeciality, Collectors.counting()));
```

Finally, you can find the maximum value in a similar manner to how you have described above. But please do take care to handle the event that two (or more) specialities have the same count.

Comment: Why not simply add a second param to groupBy, i.e `Map<String, Long> grouped =doctorList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Doctor::getSpeciality,Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: @Eritrean great suggestion, I will update my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it may be better to collect into a map using `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting`:

```java
Map.Entry<String, Long> specializationMax = doctorList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Doctor::getSpeciality, Collectors.counting()
    ))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .get();
```

Or `Collectors::collectingAndThen` may be used with `Collectors.toMap` and a finisher function to convert the map into max entry:

```java
Map.Entry<String, Integer> specializationMax = doctorList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(Doctor::getSpeciality, x -> 1, Integer::sum), 
        (map) -> map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .get()
    )
);
```